# c++ vector assign object from constructor without temporary

Tags: c++, templates, vector

i have a class voxel, which is made with a template, the parameter dim being the space dimension (2D/3D):

```
template<int dim>
class Voxel{
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, dim, 1> vect;
private:
    vect Position; 
    vect Frequence; 

public:
    Voxel(vector<float>&, vector<float>& );
};

template<int dim>
Voxel<dim>::Voxel(vector<float> &coordinates, vector<float> &frequence){
    assert( ((dim==2) || (dim==3)) && "Spatial dimension at voxel   creation must be 2 or 3");
    for (int i; i<dim; ++i){
        Position[i] = coordinates[i]; 
        Frequence[i] = frequence[i];
     }
}
```

In another object: i have

```
template<int dim>
class Grid{
private:
    vector<float> size;
    vector<Voxel<dim>> voxels; ///< @brief List of the points. Maybe should be pointers ?
    unsigned int nb_voxels; ///< @brief total number of voxels in the grid
public:
    Grid(vector<float>&, vector<int>& );
};

template<int dim>
Grid<dim>::Grid(vector<float> &size, vector<int> &resolution)
    : size(size)
{
    nb_voxels = resolution[0];
    for (int d = 1; d < dim; ++d) {
        nb_voxels *= resolution[d];
    }
    voxels.resize(nb_voxels);
    vector<float> pos;
    pos.resize(dim);
    vector<float> freq;
    freq.resize(dim);

    vector<float> possible_coordinates;
    possible_coordinates.resize(nb_voxels);
    for (int d = 0; d < dim; ++d) {
        for (int k = 0; k < resolution[d] ; ++k) {
            possible_coordinates[k + d*resolution[d]] = k * size[d]/(resolution[d]-1); //ok
        }
    }

    for (int elem = 0; elem < nb_voxels; ++elem) {
        for (int d = 0; d < dim; ++d) {
            pos[d] = 0; //fixme
        }
        Voxel<dim> v(pos, freq);
        voxels[elem]= v;
    }
    cout << "nb points="<< nb_voxels <<endl;
}
```

And finally the main:

```
int main (){

    vector<float> dimensions = {4, 8};
    vector<int> resolution = {2, 4}; ///< @brief must be >1 on each dim

        space_dim = dimensions.size();

    for (int d = 0; d < space_dim; ++d) {
        assert( (resolution[d]%2 == 0) && "resolution must be even");
    }

    if (space_dim == 2) {
        Grid<2> Grid(dimensions, resolution);
    }
    else if (space_dim == 3){
        Grid<3> Grid(dimensions, resolution);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why cannot i do this ?

```
voxels[elem] = Voxel<dim>(pos, freq);
```

nor this:

```
Voxel<dim> v (pos, freq);
voxels[elem] = v;
```

but i could: no resize vector and do:

```
    Voxel<dim> v(pos, freq);
    voxels.push_back(v);
```

I thought Voxel(pos, freq) would return an instance of the object and copy it in the element ?

thanks

Comment: Probably something broken in your `Voxel` class template (like the copy constructor or assignment operator taking non-const reference). Better post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK, I see you changed the question completely. Still, you don't have an MCVE.

Comment: excuse me, i forgot the main and a constructor. I think everything is there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `std::vector::resize` which will call the default constructor of the value type, but there isn't one in `Voxel`, so you get a compile-time error.

Use `std::vector::reserve` to allocate the memory without attempting default construction.

Comment: thanks,This seems to work, both at compile time and running. (i can print in gdb voxels[3].position[0] and i seem to get the correct result.
I don't get why the resize doesn't work though, in [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/). Could you provide more reference please ?

Comment: From that link "If n is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of val, otherwise, they are value-initialized". This means that memory is allocated *and* the objects are initialized with the default constructor. `Voxel` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: ok, i think i understand. thank you. That means i have to have a constructor Voxel(), whch seems to work. many thanks

Comment: If you want to use `resize`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> voxels[elem]

returns a reference (invalid) to the element at position `elem` since the vector is empty. You need to first push elements to the vector by using `std::vector::resize` which will push elements to the vector by calling the default constructor, in order to use the `operator[]`. This should work:

```
vector<Voxel<dim>> voxels(nb_voxels);  //push nb_voxels to voxels vector
```

or

```
vector<Voxel<dim>> voxels;
voxels.resize(nb_voxels);
```

And then

```
voxels[elem] = Voxel<dim>(pos, freq);
```

Comment: thanks.i do have vector<Voxel<dim>> voxels; in the class definition, and i do voxels.resize(nb_voxels); in Grid<dim>::Grid(...)
Nevertheless, voxels[elem] = Voxel<dim>(pos, freq) return a compilator error error: no matching function for call to ‘Voxel<2>::Voxel()’